# JMockit withCapture not working

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, jmockit

Verifications in jmockit with withCapture capturing an object does not quite work. Any help?

```
@Injectable
private API _api;

@Tested
private ServiceImpl _service;

@Test
public void test(){
    new Verifications() {
        {
            VirtualUser user;
            _api.add(user = withCapture());
            Assert.assertEquals("1", user.getId());
            Assert.assertEquals("user", user.getUsername());
        }
    };
    _service.add("1","user");
}
```

Exception: null pointer in user.getId().

Comment: Can you show an executable test? This fragment doesn't show where `_api` is mocked.

Comment: @Rogério here it is mocked.

Comment: Thanks, and I see the mistake now (should have seen it before...).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Verification blocks (`new Verifications() { ... }`) are supposed to come *after* having executed the code under test. In the example test, the verification is executed before, so there is nothing to capture into the `user` variable at that moment. Therefore, it remains `null`. Simply move the verification block to the end of the test method.